# Pandas: Split string on last occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a column in a pandas dataframe based on a separator character, and obtain the last section.

pandas has the str.rsplit and the str.rpartition functions.

If I try:

```
df_client["Subject"].str.rsplit("-", 1)
```

I get

> 0 [Activity -Location ,  UserCode]
>   1 [Activity -Location ,  UserCode]

and if I try

```
df_client["Subject"].str.rpartition("-")
```

I get

> ```
>       0            1      2
> ```
>
> 0  Activity -Location  -   UserCode
>   1  Activity -Location  -   UserCode

If I do

```
df_client["Subject"].str.rpartition("-")[2]
```

I get

> 0 UserCode

which is what I want.

To me, str.rsplit seems unintuitive.

*After getting the list of the split string, how would I then select the single item that I need?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think need [indexing by str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) working with iterables:

```
#select last lists 
df_client["Subject"].str.rsplit("-", 1).str[-1]
#select second lists
df_client["Subject"].str.rsplit("-", 1).str[1]
```

If performance is important use `list comprehension`:

```
df_client['last_col'] = [x.rsplit("-", 1)[-1] for x in df_client["Subject"]]
print (df_client)
                      Subject  last_col
0  Activity-Location-UserCode  UserCode
1  Activity-Location-UserCode  UserCode
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `expand=True`:

```
df_client["Subject"].str.split('-', expand=True)[2]
```

Comment: It should be `str.rsplit('-', expand=True)[1]` since I am going right-to-left. Didn't know about `expand=True`, that's useful to know.

Comment: @Alan Did you want to get `UserCode`?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the question that I was after UserCode.

Comment: @Alan Maybe I am misinterpreting, but if your initial string is `Activity-Location-UserCode`, then `.str.rsplit('-', expand=True)[1]`  would give you `Location` instead of `UserCode`.

Comment: No, because rsplit starts at the end and goes left. It would see `Activity-Location-UserCode`, and then split to `Activity-Location, UserCode`, because `maxsplit=1`. Without setting `maxsplit`, yes you would be correct in saying `[1]` would give `Location` - in which case there would be no difference in using `split` or `rsplit`.

Comment: @Alan I apologize, I meant `.split` as in my answer, not `.rsplit`.

Comment: @Alan With `.split` you need `[2]` to get `UserCode`.

Comment: Yes, the key point (that I didn't mention in the question as it's not overly relevant to the question but is to this discussion) is that I don't know how many of the separator characters will appear. `Split ... [2]` only works for a specific number of separators. However, since I am always after the *last* item, `rsplit ... [1]` is the most appropriate as it will work no matter the number of separators.